# CSS Float Bottom of Image

Tags: html, css, css-position

Trying to float a box on the bottom of this image slider. Essentially the slider will have a title and caption but I also want to have a box at the bottom of the image which will pull in data using PHP.

Anyway, my problem is trying to get the white box with text to sit on the bottom of the image and stay there. If the user decreases screen size the white box should follow and stay on the bottom.

jsFiddle provided: http://jsfiddle.net/fkpe1py6/1/

```
<div id="homepage-slider-wrap" class="clr flexslider-container">
<div id="homepage-slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides clr">
        <li class="homepage-slider-slide">
            <div class="homepage-slide-inner container">
                <div class="homepage-slide-content">
                    <div class="homepage-slide-box">Float this box at the bottom of the image.</div>
                </div>
                <!-- .homepage-slider-content -->
            </div>
            <img src="http://wpexplorer-demos.com/elegant/wp-content/uploads/sites/83/2012/08/game.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- .slides -->
</div>
<!-- .flexslider -->
</div>
<!-- #homepage-slider" -->
```

CSS (see jsFiddle for full CSS)

```
.homepage-slide-box {
float:left;
bottom: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
background: #31c68b;
font-size: 1.333em;
font-weight: 600;
color: #212121;
padding: 10px;
background: #fff;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: will all your images be of the same ratio of height to width inside the slider?

Comment: @haxxxton Yes they will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change a couple of things:

I would place the `img` tag inside the `.homepage-slide-content` class `div` (this will help the `div` to know the height of the image).

then add some things to your CSS so that your other slide `div`s mimic this height.

**CSS**

```
.homepage-slider-slide{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
.homepage-slider-slide img{
    display:block;
}
.homepage-slide-inner {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.homepage-slide-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.homepage-slide-box {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #31c68b;
    font-size: 1.333em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #212121;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 350px;
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fkpe1py6/5/)**

Comment: Thanks. This works great! Question. Essentially this will showcase multiple slides. What would be the best way to position a DIV on top of these slides but WON'T be associated with the slides? - Basically it will sit on top of these slides with the banners sliding underneath.

Comment: either wrap `homepage-slider-wrap` in another wrapper and then `position:absolute` your new `div` how you like relative to it.. or place it just inside `homepage-slider-wrap` and then again `position:absolute` it, you'll need to add `position:relative` to `homepage-slider-wrap` though `:)`

Comment: @user1628845 looks good, just add `position:relative;` to `homepage-slider-wrap` and you'll be set `:)`

Answer (score 0):

remove this css positioning

```
.homepage-slide-inner {
   position: relative;
}
```

and add this

```
.homepage-slider-slide {
    position: relative;
}
```

and change position of `top: 50px` to `.homepage-slide-content {bottom : 0}`

**[jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkpe1py6/6/)**